# Measuring transaction latency and throughput in a multi node local private network

Tags: go-ethereum, ethash, pow

I'm quite new to Ethereum. I'll give a bit of context of my setup.

I have created an Ethereum private network with Ethash (PoW) as the consensus algorithm. I’m aware of the resource consumption of this protocol (I need to analyze this protocol) .Each node (Geth) is deployed in a Docker container and all nodes are discoverable. I'd like to send some transactions to stress the system and measure transaction latency and throughput. What's the best way to do so? Are there any logs I can analyse after stressing the system?

I’m not looking for tools like ethstats, I need to collect these measurements and plot some graphs.

Comment: Sometime ago I saw this project https://github.com/Trebuchet-Framework/Trebuchet-Box-Ethereum, but I've never had time to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a blockchain network monitor (like https://ethstats.io). The expected result looks like this:

[image]

You can run the dashboard (and supporting components) in docker containers. Find here a detailed description: https://medium.com/alethio/a-guide-to-deploying-alethios-free-open-source-products-18216617722e

Then you need for each node the ether stats client to send data to the dashboard. With this dashboard you should get all performance details you need.

*Just a comment:
Don't use a PoW chain as private network, unless you have an academic interest. You should rather use PoA, because this is less expensive in terms of cpu usage.*

Comment: Thanks for you answer Markus! I'm doing this for analysing specifically PoW and I'm trying to collect the data and plot it by myself. I was aware of ethstats and it seems like they use a real-time approach. For my case I'd like to analyse the blockchain after having sent the transactions, however I'm not sure how I can do this, through logs or directly accessing the blockchain maybe?