# Throughput and Latency of Private Ethereum Network

Tags: transactions, blockchain, private-blockchain, network, private

How do I calculate Throughput and Latency of a private Ethereum network that I have set up locally on my computer? I tried the solution given in [Measuring transaction latency and throughput in a multi node local private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94591/measuring-transaction-latency-and-throughput-in-a-multi-node-local-private-netwo) but did not help.

I am fine even if there is a way to manually calculate any performance metrics of Ethereum network

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Caliper can be used to measure throughput and latency of private ethereum.

https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/ethereum-config/